# generated class(es) have compilation errors

Tags: wsdl2apex

I'm trying to generate apex class from wsdl file. But it shows error "ClientSystemException: Exception class must extend another Exception class at 176:18"
[This is wsdl file.](https://stage.totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service/webservice?wsdl)

Thank you.

Comment: try using online wsdl parser http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Wsdl-Parsing-Web-Version.aspx

Comment: Now i'm getting error:"Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: WebServiceCallout.invoke(totalcheckSensisComAuService.TotalCheckServiceImplPort, totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddress, Map<String,totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResponse>, List<String>) at line 772 column 13"

Comment: Sorry sir i don't understand,

Comment: check this link https://gist.github.com/RatanPaul/f1932311fa8db34e924c I have generated apex class from your WSDL

Comment: Yeah sir, i got it.. but it generate error " Method does not exist or incorrect signature" like this.

Comment: where you are getting method doesnot exist error?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: WebServiceCallout.invoke(totalcheckSensisComAuService.TotalCheckServiceImplPort, totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddress, Map<String,totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResponse>, List<String>) at line 772 column 13

Comment: no idea why it is not working for you. Just now I saved this file in my org no issue.

Comment: Maybe it's a long shot, but perhaps you have created a class in the same org called WebServiceCallout?

Answer (score 2):

The WSDL has the complexType `ClientSystemException`.

```
<xs:complexType name="ClientSystemException">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
```

When this gets turned into an inner Apex class by the default Wsdl2Apex implementation it will have the name "ClientSystemException". Apex has a requirements that all exception classes extend another Exception class, which leads to the error:

> ClientSystemException: Exception class must extend another Exception class

In your case, you can either make the generated inner class ClientSystemException extend Exception, or change the generated class name.

If you use the latest version of the [FuseIT Wsdl2Apex](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) implementation you get this extract:

```
public class ClientSystemException_x {
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
}
```

I was able to deploy the resulting Apex class to Salesforce.

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
//Methods Included: suggestNames, suggestAddresses, selectAddress
// Primary Port Class Name: TotalCheckServiceImplPort   
public class totalcheckSensisComAuService {
    public class addressDetail {
        public String barcode;
        public String bsp;
        public String buildingName;
        public String dpid;
        public String formattedAddress;
        public String postcode;
        public String state;
        public String streetName;
        public String streetNumber;
        public String streetSuffix;
        public String streetType;
        public String subPremise;
        public String suburb;
        private String[] barcode_type_info = new String[]{'barcode','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] bsp_type_info = new String[]{'bsp','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] buildingName_type_info = new String[]{'buildingName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] dpid_type_info = new String[]{'dpid','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] formattedAddress_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddress','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] postcode_type_info = new String[]{'postcode','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] state_type_info = new String[]{'state','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetName_type_info = new String[]{'streetName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetNumber_type_info = new String[]{'streetNumber','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetSuffix_type_info = new String[]{'streetSuffix','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetType_type_info = new String[]{'streetType','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] subPremise_type_info = new String[]{'subPremise','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] suburb_type_info = new String[]{'suburb','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'barcode','bsp','buildingName','dpid','formattedAddress','postcode','state','streetName','streetNumber','streetSuffix','streetType','subPremise','suburb'};
    }
    public class addressSearch {
        public String formattedAddress;
        public Boolean formattedAddressIncludesPostcode;
        public Boolean formattedAddressIncludesState;
        public Boolean formattedAddressIncludesSuburb;
        public String name;
        public String options;
        public String phoneNumber;
        public String postcode;
        public String searchType;
        public String state;
        public String streetName;
        public String streetNumber;
        public String streetType;
        public String suburb;
        private String[] formattedAddress_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddress','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] formattedAddressIncludesPostcode_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddressIncludesPostcode','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] formattedAddressIncludesState_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddressIncludesState','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] formattedAddressIncludesSuburb_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddressIncludesSuburb','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] name_type_info = new String[]{'name','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] options_type_info = new String[]{'options','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] phoneNumber_type_info = new String[]{'phoneNumber','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] postcode_type_info = new String[]{'postcode','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] searchType_type_info = new String[]{'searchType','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] state_type_info = new String[]{'state','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetName_type_info = new String[]{'streetName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetNumber_type_info = new String[]{'streetNumber','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetType_type_info = new String[]{'streetType','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] suburb_type_info = new String[]{'suburb','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddress','formattedAddressIncludesPostcode','formattedAddressIncludesState','formattedAddressIncludesSuburb','name','options','phoneNumber','postcode','searchType','state','streetName','streetNumber','streetType','suburb'};
    }
    public class addressSuggestion {
        public String formattedAddress;
        public Integer index;
        public Boolean postal;
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressSearch search_x;
        public String secondaryName;
        public Boolean whitePages;
        private String[] formattedAddress_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddress','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] index_type_info = new String[]{'index','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','int','1','1','false'};
        private String[] postal_type_info = new String[]{'postal','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] search_x_type_info = new String[]{'search','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','addressSearch','0','1','false'};
        private String[] secondaryName_type_info = new String[]{'secondaryName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] whitePages_type_info = new String[]{'whitePages','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddress','index','postal','search_x','secondaryName','whitePages'};
    }
    public class ClientSystemException_x {
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }
    public class selectAddress {
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressSuggestion suggestion;
        private String[] suggestion_type_info = new String[]{'suggestion','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','addressSuggestion','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'suggestion'};
    }
    public class selectAddressResponse {
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResult return_x;
        private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','selectAddressResult','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
    }
    public class selectAddressResult {
        public String[] alternativePhoneNumbers;
        public String barcode;
        public String bsp;
        public String buildingName;
        public String debug;
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressDetail[] detailList;
        public String dpid;
        public String formattedAddress;
        public Boolean inPrintedWpBook;
        public String phoneNumber;
        public Boolean postal;
        public String postcode;
        public String primaryName;
        public Integer resultStatus;
        public String secondaryName;
        public String state;
        public String streetName;
        public String streetNumber;
        public String streetSuffix;
        public String streetType;
        public String subPremise;
        public String suburb;
        public Boolean whitePages;
        public String wpListingType;
        private String[] alternativePhoneNumbers_type_info = new String[]{'alternativePhoneNumbers','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','-1','true'};
        private String[] barcode_type_info = new String[]{'barcode','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] bsp_type_info = new String[]{'bsp','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] buildingName_type_info = new String[]{'buildingName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] debug_type_info = new String[]{'debug','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] detailList_type_info = new String[]{'detailList','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','addressDetail','0','-1','true'};
        private String[] dpid_type_info = new String[]{'dpid','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] formattedAddress_type_info = new String[]{'formattedAddress','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] inPrintedWpBook_type_info = new String[]{'inPrintedWpBook','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] phoneNumber_type_info = new String[]{'phoneNumber','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] postal_type_info = new String[]{'postal','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] postcode_type_info = new String[]{'postcode','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] primaryName_type_info = new String[]{'primaryName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] resultStatus_type_info = new String[]{'resultStatus','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','int','1','1','false'};
        private String[] secondaryName_type_info = new String[]{'secondaryName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] state_type_info = new String[]{'state','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetName_type_info = new String[]{'streetName','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetNumber_type_info = new String[]{'streetNumber','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetSuffix_type_info = new String[]{'streetSuffix','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] streetType_type_info = new String[]{'streetType','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] subPremise_type_info = new String[]{'subPremise','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] suburb_type_info = new String[]{'suburb','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] whitePages_type_info = new String[]{'whitePages','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] wpListingType_type_info = new String[]{'wpListingType','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'alternativePhoneNumbers','barcode','bsp','buildingName','debug','detailList','dpid','formattedAddress','inPrintedWpBook','phoneNumber','postal','postcode','primaryName','resultStatus','secondaryName','state','streetName','streetNumber','streetSuffix','streetType','subPremise','suburb','whitePages','wpListingType'};
    }
    public class suggestAddresses {
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressSearch search_x;
        private String[] search_x_type_info = new String[]{'search','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','addressSearch','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'search_x'};
    }
    public class suggestAddressesResponse {
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddressesResult return_x;
        private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','suggestAddressesResult','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
    }
    public class suggestAddressesResult {
        public String debug;
        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressSuggestion[] resultList;
        public Integer resultStatus;
        private String[] debug_type_info = new String[]{'debug','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] resultList_type_info = new String[]{'resultList','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','addressSuggestion','0','-1','true'};
        private String[] resultStatus_type_info = new String[]{'resultStatus','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','int','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'debug','resultList','resultStatus'};
    }
    public class suggestNames {
        public String searchType;
        public String name;
        private String[] searchType_type_info = new String[]{'searchType','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] name_type_info = new String[]{'name','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'searchType','name'};
    }
    public class suggestNamesResponse {
        public String[] return_x;
        private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','string','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
    }
    public class TotalCheckServiceImplPort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://stage.totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service/webservice';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service','totalcheckSensisComAuService'};

        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResult selectAddress(totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressSuggestion suggestion) {
            totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddress request_x = new totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddress();
            totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResponse response_x;
            request_x.suggestion = suggestion;
            Map<String, totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service',
                'selectAddress',
                'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service',
                'selectAddressResponse',
                'totalcheckSensisComAuService.selectAddressResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.return_x;
        }

        public totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddressesResult suggestAddresses(totalcheckSensisComAuService.addressSearch search_x) {
            totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddresses request_x = new totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddresses();
            totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddressesResponse response_x;
            request_x.search_x = search_x;
            Map<String, totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddressesResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddressesResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service',
                'suggestAddresses',
                'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service',
                'suggestAddressesResponse',
                'totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestAddressesResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.return_x;
        }

        public String[] suggestNames(String searchType,String name) {
            totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestNames request_x = new totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestNames();
            totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestNamesResponse response_x;
            request_x.searchType = searchType;
            request_x.name = name;
            Map<String, totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestNamesResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestNamesResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service',
                'suggestNames',
                'http://totalcheck.sensis.com.au/service',
                'suggestNamesResponse',
                'totalcheckSensisComAuService.suggestNamesResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.return_x;
        }
    }
}
```